# next.js 13.4 app router layout rendering hierarchy issue and cookies in middle-ware(cookies undefined immediately after setting)

Tags: next.js

In NextJs 13.4 app router, layout.tsx is equivalent to that of _app.tsx in page router. But it's order of execution is different (i.e: page.tsx is rendered before the layout.tsx). Here, the  problem is that we can't able to create global server-context(data sharing between server components) in entry-point file (layout.tsx).

And another issue i am facing is that if i am trying to set the browser cookie using middleware.ts file, i am unable to read the cookie in a page.tsx/layout.tsx (i.e: it shows undefined). But after refreshing the page i can able to view the cookies in log.

Pls help me to overcome the above issues.

Thankyou!!!

I am expecting that layout.txt should before the page.tsx.

And to access the cookies in layout.tsx/page.tsx immediately after setting in middleware.ts.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't use React context API in server components, there are several techniques you can utilize to share data between server components.

1. Pass data as props:

```
export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const data = await fetchData();

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <ServerComponentA data={data} />
        <ServerComponentB data={data} />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

2. You can fetch the data independently in each component that needs the data. Next automatically [deduplicates](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching#automatic-fetch-request-deduping) `fetch` requests for the same data. If you're unable to use `fetch`, React provides a [cache function](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/caching#react-cache) to allow you to manually cache data for the duration of the request.

As to the cookies issue in middleware, this appears to be a known issue - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49442

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But both 1. and 2. having draw-backs for my use-case. I would like to know the two issues which I have mentioned above is the framework-level issue ? If so....Can we point-out this issue to the Vercel team to make update in their upcoming patch release?